# ios Map Refresh by the Minute ?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm getting location information(Lat,Long,Speed...) via a my web service.(wcf & json)

ios get the data I want to show on the map(binding), for example, 1 to 2 minutes, I want to refresh the map.

map(mkmapview or google ios map)

How can I do this? Is the article or sample?

Thank u.

Comment: you wanna update pins in that map right ? @SametG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(refreshMap:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  //60 represents 60 sec.

-(void)refreshMap:(NSTimer *)timer {
    //Map refresh code.
}
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: thank u, try to make..

I have another question, which car is better ios map kit or google ios map kit ?

Comment: I would suggest Apple’s MapKit, especially if you’re a beginner, its very easy to implement and offers better integration into iOS. But point to be consider is the data quality can be problematic.If quality is of more importance to you or require features better than MapKit, I would suggest you to go for Google's Maps SDK.

Comment: add annotations(50-100psc) with the timer on the mapview but the timer is running 1 of 2 seconds freezes mapview. How do I fix it? :(